# problema con el espaciado de visual estudio

Tags: css, visual-studio, css-grid-layout

quisiera que me ayudaran en algo, lo que pasa es que visual studio siempre que guardo reordena el código haciendo imposible hacer grid-template-areas porque pone todos los atributos en una fila de nuevo

[image: asi es como visual studio me lo reordena cada ves que guardo los cambios]

[image: asi es como quiero que quede el codigo]
quisiera quitar lo de reordenar codigo pero no se como